# Get the representation of {x,\theta} with the given equations

Tags: equation-solving

I am working with a Transfer funtion problem. I want to get the representation of {x, $\theta$} with the given equtions(below).

[image: to be solved eqns]

In the equation x10 and x20 means the initial value of x1 and x2. all the other letter is undetermined.

I want to get the represented form of {x, \theta} based on these two equations.

Here is my code:

```
ClearAll[x, \[Theta], c];
{a, b} = {{1, -L/2}, {1, L/2}}.{x, \[Theta]};
{Subscript[F, 1], Subscript[F, 
   2]} = {{k + c s, 0}, {0, k + c s}}.{a, 
     b} - {{k + c s, 0}, {0, k + c s}}.{Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 
     2]} + c {x10, x20};
eqn = {x, \[Theta]} - {{1/(M s^2), 1/(M s^2)}, {-L/(2 J), L/(
       2 J)}}.{Subscript[F, 1], Subscript[F, 2]} + {g/s^2, 0} == {0, 
    0};
Assuming[{s != 0, M != 0, J != 0},
 Reduce[eqn // Thread, {x, \[Theta]}, Reals]]
```

This is the output:

> Reduce::nsmet: 无法利用 Reduce 现有的方法求解该系统.

the chinses characters means "you can't use the original methods in Reduce` to solve this system"

Thanks all.

Comment: The problem is that `Subscript[x,1]` (same with 2) is treated as a "function" of `x`. `Solve` and `Reduce` do not do not try to distinguish things like `Sin[x]` (clearly functionally dependent on `x`) from `notSin[x]` (which might or might not have some underlying dependency).

Comment: that's quite helpful!thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your input:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
{a, b} = {{1, -L/2}, {1, L/2}}.{x, θ};
{f1, f2} = {{k + c s, 0}, {0, k + c s}}.{a, b} -
 {{k + c s, 0}, {0, k + c s}}.{x1, x2} + c {x10, x20};
eqn = {x, θ} - {{1/(M s^2), 1/(M s^2)}, {-L/(2 J), 
   L/(2 J)}}.{f1, f2} + {g/s^2, 0} == {0, 0};
Solve[{eqn, s != 0, M != 0, J != 0}, {x, θ}] // FullSimplify
```

> `{{x -> (g M + k (x1 + x2) + c (-x10 + s (x1 + x2) - x20))/(2 k + s (2 c - M s)), 
>    θ -> (L (k (-x1 + x2) + c (x10 + s (-x1 + x2) - x20)))/(-2 J + L^2 (k + c s))}}`

**EDIT**

To use subscripted symbols one can define `Format` like this:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Format[x1] := Subscript[x, 1]
Format[x2] := Subscript[x, 2]
{a, b} = {{1, -L/2}, {1, L/2}}.{x, θ};
{f1, f2} = {{k + c s, 0}, {0, k + c s}}.{a, b} -
 {{k + c s, 0}, {0, k + c s}}.{x1, x2} + c {x10, x20};
eqn = {x, θ} - {{1/(M s^2), 1/(M s^2)}, {-L/(2 J), L/(2 J)}}.{f1, f2} + 
 {g/s^2, 0} == {0, 0};
Solve[{eqn, s != 0, M != 0, J != 0}, {x, θ}] // FullSimplify
```

now the output contains `Subscript` objects:

> ```
> {{x -> (g*M + k*(Subscript[x, 1] + Subscript[x, 2]) +            
>   c*(-x10 + s*(Subscript[x, 1] + Subscript[x, 2]) - x20))/(2*k + s*(2*c - M*s)), 
>   θ -> (L*(k*(-Subscript[x, 1] + Subscript[x, 2]) + 
>   c*(x10 + s*(-Subscript[x, 1] + Subscript[x, 2]) - x20)))/(-2*J + L^2*(k + c*s))}}
> ```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This really works. But here is a question that I notice the only difference is the use of "Subscript" Function. I wander why I can't solve the question with the symbol $x_1$ instead of "x1"?

Comment: @randolf, please see my edit about using `Subscript`s.

Comment: thanks! I have read your edit here, and I understand this question now.